# MapBox Reverse Geo Encoding

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm very new to Map box and web development. I have a Lat and long with me which i want to convert it to a address name and store it in a JavaScript variable so that i can use the address name . I tried so hard to find what header file should i add for reverse encoding to work and what JavaScript i should add to achieve my goal. Thanks a lot for you time.

JS

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXNxdWlsYXgiLCJhIjoiY2tqd2ZyMJ9.7z7Eyrj3iexJ9uDVYIT0yw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location

   center: [115.83333, -32.01667], // starting position [lng, lat]
 
    zoom: 11// starting zoom
    
  
});
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({color:"#ff3300",dragable:true,scale:0.8}).setLngLat([115.83333, -32.01667]).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works by adding the geocoder plugin and setting it to reverse geocoding. As the coordinates you pass might be flipped, or out of range you need to sanity check them before passing them to the geocoder
Otherwise it will crash.

Please see my implementation below:

```js
var coordinates = document.getElementById('coordinates'); // gets element from geocoder plugin

    var coordinatesGeocoder = function(query) {
    // input validation. Decimal coordinates will be matched by this regex
    var matches = query.match(
        /^[ ]*(?:Lat: )?(-?\d+\.?\d*)[, ]+(?:Lng: )?(-?\d+\.?\d*)[ ]*$/i
        );
    if (!matches) {
        return null;
    }
     
    function coordinateFeature(lng, lat) {
        return {
            center: [lng, lat],
            geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [lng, lat]
            },
            place_name: 'Lat: ' + lat + ' Lng: ' + lng,
            place_type: ['coordinate'],
            properties: {},
            type: 'Feature'
        };
    }
     
    var coord1 = Number(matches[1]);
    var coord2 = Number(matches[2]);
    var geocodes = [];
     
    if (coord1 < -90 || coord1 > 90) {
        // must be lng, lat
        geocodes.push(coordinateFeature(coord1, coord2));
    }
     
    if (coord2 < -90 || coord2 > 90) {
        // must be lat, lng
        geocodes.push(coordinateFeature(coord2, coord1));
    }
     
    if (geocodes.length === 0) {
        // else could be either lng, lat or lat, lng
        geocodes.push(coordinateFeature(coord1, coord2));
        geocodes.push(coordinateFeature(coord2, coord1));
        }
        

     
        return geocodes;
    };
     
     
     var Geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            localGeocoder: coordinatesGeocoder,
            zoom: 10,
            placeholder: 'Adresse oder Koordinaten z.B. (10.50, 48.00)',
            mapboxgl: mapboxgl
        })
        
    map.addControl(Geocoder);
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for answering, now i get a search bar on the top of the map, where you can search the places. But what i was looking is to get the location name of where the marker is at the moment. And i want to save that name in a JavaScript variable. Thanks a lotttt !!!